# SqlDataAdapater.Fill(dataTable) not returning rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ado.net

I have an obscure issue with a `SqlDataAdapter` not filling the datatable with a row.  This fails only on a production release.

It works on

- Debug mode on developers machine
- Release mode on developers machine

We have recently added some audit logging on all our tables and we have 2 triggers that run.  1 on the table itself which pushes a row copy as JSON to our audit log table.  And then a second trigger on the AuditLog table itself, which is as follows:

```
CREATE or ALTER   TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_AuditLog_Insert] ON  [dbo].[AuditLog] AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @Qry varchar(255)      
                        
    SELECT 
            @Qry = event_info
        FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS es
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(es.session_id, NULL) AS ib
        WHERE es.session_id = @@SPID
    
        UPDATE AuditLog 
        SET 
            [CallerProc] = @Qry
        FROM 
            AuditLog al 
            INNER JOIN inserted i on i.AuditLogID=al.AuditLogID

END
```

Basically it just updates the AuditLog table and tells us which SP was run that caused the update on any audit table.

If we disable this trigger then the `SQLDataAdapater.Fill` method starts working as expected.  Basically the SQLCommand used in the Fill method is a basic stored procedure which checks credentials for login.  I've added some tracing and everything seems to work ok.  The triggers work correctly, the SQL command seems to be working correctly but the Datatable just doesn't seem to fill (until we disable the trigger).  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: ..have you checked the Important note in the Permissions of sys.dm_exec_input_buffer() ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-input-buffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions:

Comment: ok...ill look into this.  Could very well be an issue?  Strangely though the trigger still works but clearly it is having some sort of affect on returning rows

Comment: Thank you...that was it...needed to apply the correct permissions

Answer (score 1):

Ok...for those that might come across this.  The solution was to ensure that the View State Server permissions was applied for the SQL user being used in the release version of the application